# Multiple docker containers vs multiple ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have multiple microservices that I have to run independently. I am thinking of deploying them in docker containers in one ec2 instances. But then there is the question of scaling. I knowledge is ecs gives me the ability to scale. I haven't used ecs though. So my question is can I scale all my containers by creating one ec2 networks ? Or is there anything I haven't thought or know about ? Also, what is the performance issues with this deployment ?

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 2):

For the microservices deployment, one ec2 instance will never suffice for production workload considering HA, scaling, performance etc.

You should think of cluster. A compute cluster is a multi-tenant computing environment consisting of servers (called “nodes”) whose resources have been pooled together and are used to execute processes. To enable this behavior, the nodes in a cluster must be managed by some sort of cluster management framework.

So you have to choose between multiple options from Kubernets, Mesos & Marathon and AWS ECS.

The EC2 Container Service is: A cluster management framework that uses optimistic, shared state scheduling to execute processes on EC2 instances using Docker containers.

The above option provides all the functionality you looking for. So you need to analyze more of them and select the most suitable option as per your need.